# Facebook batch request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, batch-file, request

i am trying to rewrite few requests into one batch request

```
$posts = $facebook->api('/me/feed?limit=9999999');

for($i = 0; $i < count($posts['data']); $i++)
{

  $comments = $facebook->api($posts['data'][$i]['id'].'/comments');
  $likes = $facebook->api($posts['data'][$i]['id'].'/likes');

}
```

Into

```
$batch = array();

$req = array(
    'method'       => 'GET',
    "name" => "prispevky",
    'relative_url' => '/me/feed',
);

$batch[] = json_encode($req);


$req = array(
    'method'       => 'GET',
    'relative_url' => '{result=prispevky:$.data.*.from.id}/comments'
);

$batch[] = json_encode($req);

$req = array(
    'method'       => 'GET',
    'relative_url' => '{result=prispevky:$.data.*.id}/likes'
);

$batch[] = json_encode($req);        

$params = array(
    'batch' => '[' . implode(',',$batch) . ']'
);

try 
{
  $info = $facebook->api('/','POST',$params);
  print_r($info);  
} 
catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $info = null;
}
```

But i recieve error 404 Some of the aliases you requested do not exist and then list of all id of feeds on the wall. When i call just one by simple request, i will recieve it succesfully.
Can someone help me and tell where do i have an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Henry Try this with loop to $Comments & $Likes
"This will return the Comments and Likes from post data 0.  For each post beyond that you have to add a new array.  I seen how you are trying to loop the array request, i have never been able to get that method to work since comments and likes exist in a separate table so to speak."

**NOTE:**  Batch only accepts a max of 20 requests, so requesting 999999 posts to loop will still only return the first 19 set of comment / likes given the first request is the post.

---

```
$queryProfileFeed = array(
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/me/feed?fields=id%26'.$app_access_token.'' 'name' => 'getLnC', 'omit_response_on_success' => false),    
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=getLnC:$.data.0.id}/comments?fields=id%26offset=0'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/{result=getLnC:$.data.0.id}/likes?fields=id%26offset=0'),
);
$batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queryProfileFeed), 'POST');
        /* json decode response for comments */
    $Comments = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], true);
        /* json decode response for likes */
    $Likes = json_decode($batchResponse[2]['body'], true);
```

---

I use the above method but with alot more batch request to show my wall in my plugins

but i only request the first 2 comments and likes from the first 10 posts.  More than that seems to degrade performance and often timeout throwing errors like "alias does not exsist"

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Your code works, it is very similar to that mine. You have some improvement, that i have forgot like specifi jsut field id and so on.
So i update my code to do it just for field 0 and not for all of them.

'relative_url' => '/{result=prispevky:$.data.0.id}/comments'
And it works. But if i get all IDs and then ask for each one, i will save no request time.

Comment: request was not the issue was it?  i was under the impression it was data loss, pertaining to trying to batch more than 20 requests?  To which you can just create a new set of 20 for 20 limit you are requesting.

EDIT:  i am going to try this with the all statement * and see how it works, i have never actually tried to get all comments from batch with *

Comment: I just benchmarked your method, and wow the difference is remarkable "Thank You, you also solved one of my issues :-)"

You are so right omg -  **80 most recent posts and 20 comments from each,  from Facebook page in under 3 seconds.**

https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TimeLineFeedBenchMark.php?theme=dark&pageid=facebook

Comment: With some more research i found your method will only work if you can get the CVS string of ids and rebatch them some how after exploding.  Only the field ids? accepts comma seperated sting of ids, not /comments

Comment: Still there is list of not loaded information under results. I mean there: https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TimeLineFeedBenchMark.php?theme=dark&pageid=facebook  What code are you using? I have tried a lot and still no results. Just error message saying they are not existing.

Comment: Henry, i am using the method i showed you but broken into 2 batches. 1st batch grabs the page and sets up for the first 10 posts. 2nd batch retrieves the like and permalink data.

Comment: the way you are doing it creating the comma seperated list of id's which cannot be used to query in /comments or /likes only /ids=

Comment: Oh, now i see. But it would be possible to transform result=prispevky:$.data.*.from.id}/comments'into FQL. There will be no problem with comma separing. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: I have not figured out how to yet, but i am still playing around with it.  So far i tried exploading the CVS id's in the batch then looping each into a single request but this is throwing errors too.  If i am able to do i will Edit in the new solution.